# How can I show my facebook time line in my iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

Hello I am in trouble with facebook time line. I m working with an app in which I want to show facebook time line. I am new with this concept. So  I am not able to understand how an i do that? If is there any example or code something which gives me some idea to do that it will be helpfull. Thanks in advance.
and please don't mark negative if you unable to answering it. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with Facebook time line?

Comment: I mean my home page of account. or you can say my profile.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FBSDKGraphRequest`. Check this out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

Comment: feed and timeline are same ?? I have no idea could u please help me out to understand. and how can I show data ? I want to use web view is it possible?

Comment: Above code will show feeds you will find in your Facebook profile.